# Нижняя панель в MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

В каком файле можно изменить нижнюю панель? [Сайт на котором это все](http://fortnite.sky-wiki.com)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Footer

Comment: Мне нужен именно файл в котором  все можно поменять.

Comment: Только в БД можно поменять.

Answer (score 0):

Все хранится в папке соответствующей темы в папке skins/.